# Error io.branch.referral.InstallListener Class Not Found Crash Ionic v5

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an issue with an ionic app and branch SDK, at test ENV everything works as expected but users' in PROD crash continuously.

As stated in the branch docs I have initialized branch on platform ready event at app.component.ts:

```
app.component.ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Platform } from "ionic-angular";
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from "ionic-native";

import { TabsPage } from "../pages/tabs/tabs";

@Component({
  template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
      branchInit();
    });

    platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
      branchInit();
    });

    // Branch initialization
    const branchInit = () => {
      // only on devices
      if (!platform.is("cordova")) {
        return;
      }
      const Branch = window["Branch"];
      Branch.initSession().then(data => {
        if (data["+clicked_branch_link"]) {
          // read deep link data on click
          alert("Deep Link Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      });
    };
  }
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
Unable to instantiate receiver io.branch.referral.InstallListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.branch.referral.InstallListener"
```

Here's my ionic info

```
    Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.15 (/Users/path/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.3.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 30 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : not installed
   native-run (update available: 0.3.0) : 0.2.7

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/path/Library/Android/sdk)
   NodeJS            : v9.6.0 (/Users/path/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 2.15.12
   OS                : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find good documentation about the issue and I am not sure if removing the library will result in not getting the install referrer, but after some investigation, I decided to remove these lines from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The following link talks about a communication sent by branch and outdated documentation and makes allusion to the above solution.

https://github.com/BranchMetrics/unity-branch-deep-linking-attribution/issues/171

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same issue. What version of branch are you using with this crash? I am using branchVersion="5.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be fixed with switching to new Install referrer. Because this crash started from builds that have been released in March, and it tells that from March 1, 2020 it's deprecated: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/11/still-using-installbroadcast-switch-to.html